# Linqpad use of discard (_ = underscore) throws Error CS0246 - the type or namespace name '_' could not be found

Tags: c#, linqpad

I want to learn about named tuples and discard.

Based on [C# 7.0: Tuples Explained (msdn-magazine 2017-08)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained) i created this program

```
void Main()
{

(string firstname, _, int age) user = ("surfmuggle", "discard this", 15);
user.Dump();
}
```

but it throws

> CS0246 The type or namespace name '_' could not be found (press F4 to
>   add a using directive or assembly reference)

Question

- What do i need to do to use `_` [C# 7.0 discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) inside a [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) program

Thanks

A screen of the [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) program

[image: Linqpad 6 program]

Comment: I think it should work, but it is not working for me on either LINQPad 5.41 or the current beta of 6.

Comment: *Major new features in LINQPad 5: Full support for C# 7* - its says **full** [*cough*] Maybe you should LINQPad support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to LINQPad - you'll get the same error in Visual Studio.

The problem is that you're trying to use C#'s discards in a context in which they're unsupported. From the documentation:

> In C# 7.0, discards are supported in assignments in the following
>   contexts:
>
> - Tuple and object deconstruction.
> - Pattern matching with is and switch.
> - Calls to methods with out parameters.
> - A standalone _ when no _ is in scope.

Your example would work in a deconstruction context:

```
(string firstname, _, int age) = ("surfmuggle", "discard this", 15);
firstname.Dump();
age.Dump();
```

Comment: [C# 7.0: Tuples Explained msdn-magazine 2017-08](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained) has this example `(string name, _, double gdpPerCapita) countryInfo =
("Malawi", "Lilongwe", 226.50);`

So i assume that named tuples can not be used together with discards `_`. Is this the case?